# Liferay 7 - Display localized data

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I have my Entity with a title that is localized.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><root available-locales="en_GB,fr_FR," default-locale="en_GB"><Title language-id="fr_FR">Test FR</Title><Title language-id="en_GB">TEST GB</Title></root>
```

How can i do to dispay it with my current language ?

```
<c:forEach var="service" items="${listServices}">
    <td>${service.title}</td>
</c:forEach>
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

look at `com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.LocalizationUtil` class to have all methods for this xml managment.

In particolar you need `getLocalization(String xml, String requestedLanguageId, boolean useDefault)` to extract the localized text.

bye